# LyX: how to start one cross-reference with a capital letter

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

I want a specific cross-reference in my LyX documente to start with a capital letter. In an ERT box, I have the following:

```
\Figref{fig:DesignB_Sensitivity_MAG}
```

where fig:DesignB_Sensitivity_MAG is the label of my figure. However, in the PDF what I get is

> Figure ??

Is Figref the wrong command? Does the label have to be addressed differently?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you or did Lyx) compile twice?

Comment: @Bernard, yes I have done but it still did not work.

Comment: I don't where the `\Figref` command comes from. Usually, I load `cleveref` (at  the end of the preamble) and type `\Cref` or `\cref`. The package is smart enough to determine to which environment it refers.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to capitalize the first letter and found a post where someone solve the issue using \Figref (I could not find it again to post the link here).
Anyway, your suggestion just solves my problem. Thanks @Bernard